disable global middleware from some pages - nuxt 3
When you set the middleware as global, and let's say myMid.global.ts, there are some pages on which I do not want this middleware to work. I searched and found a way using route name "to.name", and I want a better way. For example, on the page where I do not want it to work, I put, for example:
some-ex-page.vue :
<script setup lang="ts">


definePageMeta({
  myMid : false
});


</script>

Or anything else. Most pages need this middleware, but there are pages that do not. I do not think it is a good idea to go through all of these pages and manually enter the name of the middleware:
some-ex-page.vue :
<script setup lang="ts">


definePageMeta({
  middleware : ["myMid"]
});


</script>

Or, for example, there is a way to add a new property to the page. In the middleware, I can check that if this property exists, I will avoid working from this page.

Can't you check the meta of the upcoming page? What is available on the to object here?

You mean that I give the page name in definePageMeta, is there a better way?

Nah, you could have whitelist: true in the meta and check for that boolean. Again, depends on what you can have in the to object at that time. The name of the boolean is not a big deal per-se.
